# How to use latitude and longitude from Redux state to Marker coordinate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-maps, redux, react-redux

How can I access the value of longitude and latitude from Redux store and use it my Marker coordinates?

EventMap.js: This is where the Map and Marker renders.

```
{this.props.eventsState.map((marker, index) => {
                    const scaleStyle = {
                    transform: [
                        {
                            scale: interpolations[index].scale,
                        },   
                    ],
                };
                const opacityStyle = {
                    opacity: interpolations[index].opacity,
                };
                return (
                    <Marker key={index} coordinate={use it here}>
                        <Animated.View style={[styles.markerWrap, opacityStyle]}>
                            <Animated.View style={[styles.ring, scaleStyle]} />
                            <View style={styles.marker} />
                        </Animated.View>
                    </Marker>
);
```

models/realEvent.js:

```
class RealEvent {
constructor(id, title, description, imageUrl, latitude, longitude) {
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.description = description;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude
}
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
return {
    eventsState: state.events.events
};
};
```

reducer/events.js:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_EVENT:
        const newEvent = new RealEvent(
            new Date().toString(), 
            action.eventData.title, 
            action.eventData.description,
            action.eventData.imageUrl,
            action.eventData.latitude,
            action.eventData.longitude
        )
        return {
            events: state.events.concat(newEvent)
        };
        default:
            return state;
}
}
```

actions/events.js:

```
export const addEvent = (title, description, imageUrl, longitude, latitude) => {
return {
    type: ADD_EVENT,
    eventData: {
        title: title,
        description: description,
        imageUrl: 'http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/bangkok/portals/bangkok-com/homepage/top10-nightlife/pagePropertiesImage/best-nightlife-in-bangkok.jpg.jpg',
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude
    }
};
};
```

SetEventLocation.js: This is where I dispatch the value of longitude and latitude to Redux

```
const [latitude, setLatitude] = useState(null);
const [longitude, setLongitude] = useState(null);

pickLocationHandler = event => {
    const coords = event.nativeEvent.coordinate;
    map.animateToRegion({
        latitude: coords.latitude,
        longitude: coords.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
        longitudeDelta: 0.0421
    });
    console.log(coords);
    setLatitude(coords.latitude);
    setLongitude(coords.longitude)
}

const saveLocationHandler = () => {
    dispatch(eventsActions.addEvent(title, description, latitude, longitude));
    props.navigation.goBack();
};

return (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.done} onPress={saveLocationHandler}>
            <Text style={styles.doneText}>Done</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
);
```

Comment: Is the EventMap.js connected to the store? Looks like the `mapStateToProps` function you defined in `realEvent.js` should be placed in ´EventMap.js` and be used with react-redux `connect` function to subscribe to the events array in the store

Comment: Connection of `EventMap.js` and my Redux Store is properly connected because in `EventMap.js` there's a part of my App that I already output data from Redux Store so this won't be the issue